# SHA1PRNG ON IBM JRE

Tags: java

I used these code in my application :

```
    SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    secureRandom.setSeed("12345678".getBytes());
```

I found these give me different result on ibm jre than sun jre.I used it in a DES algorithm.

And I found in IBM doc:

"SHA1PRNG is a Pseudo Random Number Generator and is supplied for code compatibility. SHA1PRNG is not guaranteed to produce the same output as the SUN SHA1PRNG.
"

I used the SecureRandom in a DES algorithm, so I need the same output on different jre. Is there any way to get same output as SUN SHA1PRNG on ibm jre?

Comment: Why are you using a PRNG and expecting a consistent output? Are you sure you shouldn't be using a PBKDF?

Comment: If you could force the output, it wouldn't be very random, would it?  What are you using the random number for in the DES algorithm?

Comment: I want to implement a Des encrypt , and I found code like this:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/velocity/sandbox/velosurf/src/java/org/apache/velocity/velosurf/util/DESCryptograph.java